# Multiple SQL MAX when items are not in order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data as below:

```
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE 
(productName varchar(13), test1  int,test2  int)


INSERT INTO @MyTable
    (productName, test1,test2)
VALUES
    ('a', 1,1),
    ('a', 2,2),
    ('a', 3,3),
    ('b', 1,4),
    ('b', 2,5),
    ('b', 3,6),
    ('a', 1,7),
    ('a', 4,8),
    ('a', 5,9)
;
SELECT productname,MAX(test1) from @MyTable group BY productname
```

a MAX query on test1 column gives

```
a,5 
b,3
```

but I need to have result as

```
a,3 
b,3 
a,5
```

when I have order by test2

Comment: Where is this "MAX query?"  Can you show us your expected result set for the other query?

Comment: can you explain why a,3 and a,5? because if you want max of first 3 a, and then max of last 3 a, your problem is table schema design

Comment: it is data in database

Comment: I mean explain why your result is a,3 and a,5

Comment: your first result is correct as per the query, can you explain your second result?

Comment: Assuming that your data will be ordered by test2, then what you need is `RANK()`

Comment: As @JuanCarlosOropeza said explain why you should have 'a,3' and 'a,5' but not 'a,4'

Comment: It is max per group and grouping is base on the order by test2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using a trick with row_numbers, so that you assign 2 different row numbers, one for the whole data and one that is partitioned by productname. If you compare the difference between these numbers, you can figure out when product name has changed, and use that to determine the max values for each group.

```
select productname, max(test1) from (
SELECT *,
    row_number() over (order by test2 asc) -
    row_number() over (partition by productname order by test2 asc) as GRP 
from @MyTable
) X 
group by productname, GRP
```

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e943/1)

If the test2 column is always a row number without gaps, you can use that too instead of the first row number column. If you need ordering in the data, you'll have to for example to use the max of test1 to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following SQL Select statement

```
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE (productName varchar(13), test1  int,test2  int)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
    (productName, test1,test2)
VALUES
    ('a', 1,1),
    ('a', 2,2),
    ('a', 3,3),
    ('b', 1,4),
    ('b', 2,5),
    ('b', 3,6),
    ('a', 1,7),
    ('a', 4,8),
    ('a', 5,9)

DECLARE @MyTableNew AS TABLE (id int identity(1,1), productName varchar(13), test1  int,test2  int)
insert into @MyTableNew select * from @MyTable
--select * from @MyTableNew

;with cte as (
    SELECT
        id, productName, test1, test2,
        case when (lag(productName,1,'') over (order by id)) = productName then 0 else 1 end ischange
    from @MyTableNew
), cte2 as (
    select t.*,(select sum(ischange) from cte where id <= t.id) grp from cte t
)
select distinct grp, productName, max(test1) over (partition by grp) from cte2
```

This is implemented according to the following [SQL Server Lag() function tutorial](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sqlserver-lag-function-to-group-rows-on-column-value.aspx) 
The Lag() function is used to identify and order the groups in table data

Answer (score -1):

Please try this query

```
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE 
(productName varchar(13), test1  int,test2  int)


INSERT INTO @MyTable
    (productName, test1,test2)
VALUES
    ('a', 1,1),
    ('a', 2,2),
    ('a', 3,3),
    ('b', 1,4),
    ('b', 2,5),
    ('b', 3,6),
    ('a', 1,7),
    ('a', 4,8),
    ('a', 5,9)
;
SELECT productname,MAX(test1) 
from @MyTable 
where test1 = test2
group BY productname
union all
SELECT productname,MAX(test1) 
from @MyTable 
where test1 != test2
group BY productname
```

Comment: This only works in a special case when there's max 3 groups and the first one is such that all test1 values are equal to test 2